# cannot parse json to string format

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Can anyone tell me why am  no getting string format value of data after perform json parsing
ps: connection part all is working fine, now I want to add on json parsing method into it only.

```
try {
    strUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/android/login.php?username=" + u + "&password=" + p + "";
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.connect();


    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String value = bf.readLine();


    String json = value;
    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Data");
    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);


    String username = finalObject.getString("user_name");
    String result = username;
    return result;
```

This is my api result :

```
{
    "Status": "true",
    "Message": "login successfully",
    "Data": [{
        "user_name": "JS"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat.....

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to get the value of `"user_name"` from the `Data ` JSONArray ??

Comment: @Naz141 yes bro, just like what you said

Comment: @Champandorid System.out: org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
  String value;
  while ((value= r.readLine()) != null) {
      total.append(value).append('\n');
  }
  String json = value;
  JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
  JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Data");
  JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);
  String username = finalObject.getString("user_name");
  String result = username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonMainArr = jObject.getJSONArray("Data"); 

  JSONObject jsonObj = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(0);

String username = jsonObj.getString("user_name");
return username;



 private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```